# Index/Match in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, index-match

**ME** - Coding rookie, slowing learning my way through writing basic functions to reduce the amount of manual copy/pasting.

**ISSUE** - One of the things I/my teammates regularly do is use index/match (or vlookup) to populate rosters for upload into different CRMs, or for doing analysis after they have been uploaded. This can be tedious and time consuming, and is prone to errors, and I would like to know how to automate as much as possible. Using the record macros function in GSheets, I've been able to cobble together something which works (the included code), but its not really "clean" code, and is not that easy to transplant into another sheet.

**DESIRED SOLUTION** - What I would GREATLY appreciate is a framework structure that can be adapted to pull one or more pieces of information, from one or more tabs, into a single location, based on a unique ID. Essentially an expandable index/match run from a function. What would be even better than great, is if it could also work across workbooks.

**THANK YOU!!**

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H7Mf.png)

[Index/match using recorded macros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad3XC.png)

```
function importCCAinformation (){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ccaOnboardings = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('sheet URL') //source workbook
  var ccaSummary = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var coreTracker = ccaOnboardings.getSheetByName('Core-->Full Tracker') //source sheet 
  var engList = ccaOnboardings.getSheetByName('Eng List') //source sheet 

  coreTracker.copyTo(ccaSummary)
  engList.copyTo(ccaSummary)
    
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clearContent();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=index(\'Copy of Core-->Full Tracker\'!I:I,match(A2,\'Copy of Core-->Full Tracker\'!D:D,0))');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();  
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  var range = spreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var removeNA = range.createTextFinder('#N/A');
  removeNA.replaceAllWith('');
  spreadsheet.getRange('F1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(6, true);

  var coreMemberStatus = spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F').getValues();
  var lastRowCoreTracker = coreMemberStatus.filter(String).length;
  var firstRowEngList = [lastRowCoreTracker+2]

  spreadsheet.getRange('F'+firstRowEngList).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=index(\'Copy of Eng List\'!F:F,match(A'+firstRowEngList+',\'Copy of Eng List\'!A:A,0))');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F'+firstRowEngList+':F'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();  
  spreadsheet.getRange('F'+firstRowEngList).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F'+firstRowEngList+':F').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  var range = spreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var removeNA = range.createTextFinder('#N/A');
  removeNA.replaceAllWith('');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(1, true);


  const sheetNamesToDelete = ["Copy of Core-->Full Tracker","Copy of Eng List"]
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();

  const sheetsToDelete = sheets.filter(sheet => sheetNamesToDelete.includes(sheet.getSheetName()))
  
  sheetsToDelete.forEach(sheet =>{
    ss.deleteSheet(sheet)
  })
  
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code to this thread rather than a screen shot?  Its too small to read.  Simply cut and paste your code below you text.  Highlight your code and hit Ctrl-K.

Comment: Added the code! :)

Comment: You can do a lot of this with metadata but perhaps it might be wise for your organization to hire a programmer to assist you in reducing the learning curve.  Using the code from macros is not really that useful as you progress in your coding you will find the use of activate() and dependence on the active sheet will go away and the code will run more efficiently.

Comment: Small, growing company, and we don't really have the capacity for a dedicated programmer. I took it upon myself to try and learn some coding to help improve some of the processes. I have some very good, adaptable/expandable code for most of the copy/pasting that is done on a daily basis, but I am struggling with understanding the syntax around how to get a multiple tier for loop to work correctly.

Comment: Sorry, too much stuff from Macro Recorder.  Can't tell what your doing.   What you want.

Comment: I added a screen grab of a sample table - What I would like to be able to do is run a function to use the ID in column A to match to another tab, and pull in 1 or more data points from that tab. 

The macro recordings are finding a cell, pasting the formula, dragging that down, clearing the N/A (from IDs not present), sorting so all returns are together, finding the last populated row, pasting another index/match (using that last row) referencing a second tab, dragging down, clearing the N/A, then sorting by the ID in column A

Comment: If your last comment is a question then please post it as a question

Comment: Struggling is part of learning to code

Comment: My last comment was in reply to TheWizEd. I realize struggling is part of learning to code. As I said, I managed to get it working, im simply looking for some assistance in making this a cleaner, and expandable, function.

Comment: I tried to follow the script you provided but its too confusing.  You copy formulas then you overwrite with values.  Move down the sheet and do it again.  There is a lot of cleanup eliminating "N/A" and blank cells. This is more like trying to replicate the mouse and keyboard motions.  You will have a hard time trying to change this in the future.   You need to step back and organize your data and process.  Then maybe a script will work for you.

Comment: A cleaner understanding of what you want is the most important part of scripting. You need to sort the things you want to do at first, and then find a way to automate it by finding some patterns then executing it efficiently by understanding the goal you have in mind. At least you are trying to learn, but no programmer can improve a script like this especially if both process and end goal is vague.